# Error when compiling webpack in npm (laravel)

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, sass

Hi yesterday i shut down my pc and everything was fine. Today when i start npm run watch in my project this error ocurred.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                        12:02:15 PM

This dependency was not found:

* /Users/adrianmindek/Code/Stavebniny/resources/sass/xs_app.scss in multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/xs_app.scss

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /Users/adrianmindek/Code/Stavebniny/resources/sass/xs_app.scss
     Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  1.39 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/xs_app.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/adrianmindek/Code/Stavebniny/resources/sass/xs_app.scss' in '/Users/adrianmindek/Code/Stavebniny'
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/xs_app.scss /js/app[1]
```

I don't really know what is it or how to solve it i tried to use older package.json from older dev but nothing changed. Now my sass is no working anymore.

That file xs_app.scss is in folder ..../resources/sass/mobile/xs_app.scss what is weird becouse above in error the mobile folder is missing.

Webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/xs_app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Try `rm -r node_modules/
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clean -f
npm install`

Comment: I tried nothing changed

Comment: try with sudo. `sudo npm run watch`

Comment: nope. that's not it

Comment: Can you please share webpack.mix.js as well.

Comment: Thx that webpack was problem.. bad route was there... Anyway idk why it changed.

Comment: maybe due to some cache or permission issue. try removing the project "node_modules" folder. after that, delete the contents of the public compiled contents folder and then ````npm install```` and ````npm run {command}```` without "sudo". If npthing works, try restarting your PC.

Answer (score 0):

you can below command just give the project folder permission to write

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass --save
```